# Put multiple attachments on a PouchDB document in one transaction

Tags: pouchdb

I have a function that looks like this

```
var Db = new PouchDB('mydb');

function attach(doc, pictures) {
  // expecting file URI
  var blobPromises = pictures.map(function(imgUri) {
    // https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util
    return blobUtil.imgSrcToBlob(imgUri);
  });

  // angular's $q
  return $q.all(blobPromises).then(
    function gotBlobs(blobs) {
      var batchId = (new Date()).getTime();

      var attachPromises = blobs.map(function(blob, i) {
        var attachmentId = 'picture/' + batchId + '/' + i;

        // NOTE: this is throwing error 409
        return Db.putAttachment(doc._id, attachmentId, doc._rev, blob, blob.type);
      });

      return $q.all(attachPromises);
    }
  )
}
```

Now that I know what's wrong - the same `doc._rev` is being reused for *all* attachment insertion. It should work if I change my code to perform `Db.putAttachment()` *one after another* and querying the new `doc._rev` everytime.

BUT:

1. does PouchDB provides an API like `putAttachments()` like what [CouchDB has](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Multiple_Attachments)?
2. else is it possible to put attachment when creating a document through `put()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can attach as many attachments as you want to a document when you `put()` it.

Check the first example [from the guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html). You can do something like this instead:

```
db.put({
  _id: 'mydoc',
  _attachments: {
    'myattachment1.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob1
    },
    'myattachment2.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob2
    },
    'myattachment3.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob3
    },
    // etc.
  }
});
```

Comment: It works. The example looks valid only for base-64 strings so I've overlooked it. Thanks man.

Comment: I think just include an example with Blob like in this answer will be great

Comment: @nlawson How to put an array of attachments in one go? Ex: [{'id1':{"content_type":"image/png",data:blob}}, ...]

Comment: The [attachments guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html) has examples of putting multiple attachments at once.